# Electronic passport gates for US citizens at Heathrow

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, us-citizens, lhr

Can US citizens use the electronic passport gates at Heathrow airport without having to enroll beforehand in any special programs?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Brexit, unless you can elaborate further?

Comment: Hi. The intention of Travel StackExchange is to give complete answers that don't expire with time. A question about 'updates' is going to get out of date very fast, so we are probably not going to answer it.

Comment: When the UK government announces something, it will be in the news. Try a Google News alert.

Comment: What part of the question is unclear? The answer is "no".

Comment: Never mind, the question has been edited beyond all recognition

Comment: @Calchas It's exactly the same question, but with the irrelevant Brexit bit removed, and clarified so that it makes sense to people who don't closely follow the news.

Comment: "Summer 2019" https://www.gov.uk/government/news/epassport-gates-to-ease-travel-for-passengers-from-more-countries

Comment: The sign at the airport clearly states for whom the gates are valid. And if (like many people) you have trouble reading the sign, the attendants with the purple uniforms will also explain it.

Answer (score 9):

You will be able to from Summer 2019 says [this article](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/epassport-gates-to-ease-travel-for-passengers-from-more-countries) on the UK government's website, I'm pretty sure it used to say April 2019 (not 100%) though.

But at the moment you cannot use these gates, you have to see an immigration officer in the *All other passports* queue, unless you are a [registered traveller](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller/eligibility).

> From summer 2019, eligible travellers from Australia, Canada, Japan, New Zealand and **the United States** will be able to use the ePassport gates at 14 ports, both in the UK and at Eurostar terminals at Brussels and Paris.

I will update the answer when this comes into force.

**Update May 2019**

As of 20th May 2019, citizens of Australia, Canada, Japan, New Zealand, Singapore, South Korea and the **United States** can now use ePassport gates, including at Heathrow.

> From today (Monday 20 May), visitors from Australia, Canada, Japan,
>   New Zealand, Singapore, South Korea and the **United States** will be able
>   to use ePassport gates at ports across the UK and juxtaposed controls
>   in a move designed to speed up border controls for low-risk countries.

[Official government source.](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/government-expands-use-of-epassport-gates-to-7-more-countries)

Comment: Singapore and South Korea too will join these other countries.